# How must I modify bootstrap to have landscape mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, landscape

Help me please, ho do I change my css/html (using bootstrap) In order to see my page horizontaly in landscape mode ???![enter image description here][1]

http://postimg.org/image/pb7vwhusf/ this is the link to image

Answer (score 0):

Your question isnt very well worded. in bootstrap you have a wrapper div with a class of container, this has a max width, you then have a div within with a class of row and then you place divs within that with column classes.

```
<style>
.urimg{
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div clads="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <img class="urimg"  src="imgpath"/>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```